# Selenium test case is getting pass in every case either the element present on page or not

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

My selenium test case is given below:

```
@Test(priority = 1)
public void Check_Funnel_on_homepage() throws Exception {
    try {
        isElementDisplayed((By.id(propObjctRepo.getProperty("xpath_abc"))));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        addErrorlogs(e, "Error message");
    }
}
```

My test method is given below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public boolean isElementDisplayed(By element) throws Exception {
    try {
        Assert.assertTrue(dvr.findElement(element).isDisplayed());
        addlogs("Element " + element + " found on page");
        System.out.println("Element " + element + " found on page");
        return true;
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        System.out.println("Element " + element + " not found on page");
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Element " + element + " not found on page");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am facing an issue, In every case either the element present on page or not the test case is returning true and passing in testNG report.

Comment: Are you checkin if the element is displayed or present? It is not the same thing, you know...

Comment: Yes i want to check "is element displayed" or not. what is wrong in the logic, Please suggest.

Comment: remove try catch block or throw exception in the catch block. it will solve you issue.

Comment: Element can be present, but not displayed.

Comment: No its still getting pass after removing removing catch block.

Comment: @MateMrše I am putting incorrect element to make it fail, But its passing :)

Comment: Update the line Assert.assertTrue(isElementDisplayed((By.id(propObjctRepo.getProperty("xpath_abc")))); Remove try catch in Check_Funnel_on_homepage . TestNG need some assertion to mark the result.

Answer (score 3):

You don't do anything if `isElementDisplayed()` return `false`, you need to use [assert](https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.8.17/org/testng/Assert.html)

```
public void checkFunnelOnHomepage() {
    By by = By.id(propObjctRepo.getProperty("xpath_abc"));
    boolean isDisplayed = isElementDisplayed(by);
    Assert.assertTrue(isDisplayed, "Element " + by + " not found on page");
}
```

You can add the assertion message to `assertTrue()`, and change `isElementDisplayed(By element)` to only return `true` or `false`

```
public boolean isElementDisplayed(By by) {
    List<WebElement> elements = dvr.findElements(by);
    return elements.size() > 0 && elements.get(0).isDisplayed();
}
```

If you use `findElements` you avoid using `try catch`. It is also the [recommended way](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-)

> findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use
>   WebDriver.findElements(By)

Be careful using `try catch`, it will ignore the assertion error.

As a side note, according to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) `Check_Funnel_on_homepage` should be `checkFunnelOnHomepage`.

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are catching the assertion error and returning false. and doing nothing with the returned value. hence end result for your test is test case is passed